# conversion from javascript to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i have this javascript code:

```
var a = 7;
function addNumber(Number) {
    document.getElementById("display").value = 
    document.getElementById("display").value + Number;
}
function calculate() {
    a = eval(document.getElementById("display").value);
    document.getElementById("display").value = a;
}
function erase() {
    document.getElementById("display").value = '';
}
```

and i made this jquery, but it does not work

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j( document ).ready(function() {
    var a = 7;
    function addNumber(Number) {
        $j( "#display").attr( "value", ( $j( "#display").val() + Number ));
    }
    function calculate() {
        a = eval($j( "#display").val());
        $j( "#display").attr( "value", a)
    }
    function erase() {
        $j( "#display").attr( "value", '');
    }
});
```

the full code on a jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/8z6vgnqk/

Comment: How are you invoking your functions? there is not enough information here to help out... are you, for instance, including jquery in your page? - UPDATE: nevermind I see the fiddle now

Comment: You need to learn what ready is for.

Comment: jquery is javascript. what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put your functions inside `$(document).ready()`. Since you're calling them from the `onclick` attributes, they have to be in the global scope, but you have them inside a function, so their scope is local to that function.

And on jsfiddle, you also have to select `No wrap` from the frameworks menu, so they don't get put inside the `window.onload` function.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

var a = 7;

function addNumber(Number) {
    $j("#display").attr("value", ($j("#display").val() + Number));
}



function calculate() {
    a = eval($j("#display").val());
    $j("#display").attr("value", a)
}

function erase() {
    $j("#display").attr("value", '');
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8z6vgnqk/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working better way:

```
<div class="header">
    <input name="1" id="display" value="" disabled>
</div>
<div class="numberFields">
    <input type="button" name="1" value="1" onclick="alert(1);addNumber('1')"/>
    <input type="button" name="2" value="2" onclick="addNumber('2')"/>
    <input type="button" name="3" value="3" onclick="addNumber('3')"/>
    <input type="button" name="4" value="4" onclick="addNumber('4')"/>
    <input type="button" name="5" value="5" onclick="addNumber('5')"/>
    <input type="button" name="6" value="6" onclick="addNumber('6')"/>
    <input type="button" name="7" value="7" onclick="addNumber('7')"/>
    <input type="button" name="8" value="8" onclick="addNumber('8')"/>
    <input type="button" name="9" value="9" onclick="addNumber('9')"/>
    <input type="button" name="0" value="0" onclick="addNumber('0')"/>
    <input type="button" name="." value="." onclick="addNumber('.')"/>
    <input type="button" name="C" value="C" onclick="erase()"/>
</div>
<div class="operations">
    <input type="button" name="+" value="+" onclick="addNumber('+')"/>
    <input type="button" name="-" value="-" onclick="addNumber('-')"/>
    <input type="button" name="*" value="*" onclick="addNumber('*')"/>
    <input type="button" name="/" value="/" onclick="addNumber('/')"/>
</div>
<div class="sum">
    <input type="button" name="=" value="=" onclick="calculate()"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var display = $("#display");

    function addNumber(num) {
        display.val(display.val() + num);
    }

    function calculate() {
        var anwser = eval(display.val());
        display.val(anwser);
    }

    function erase() {
        display.val("");
    }

</script>
```

I'm not sure what was going on with your fiddle so I ripped the code out and stuck it all in one place.

Some notes about the code...

- No need for the document.ready as you're not accessing the DOM until you click a button.
- Rather than `$("#display").attr("value")`, use `$("#display").val()`
- If you're repeating the same selector again an again, assign it once and use that variable from then on `var display = $("#display");` then use as `display.val("");`